# React Native:object destructed return undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

My React Native 0.62.2 destructing a `props` passed into a class within `render () {}`:

```
 const {dataLen, img_source, width, ht, index, modalWidth, modalHt} = this.props;
```

Here is the console output of the `props`:

```
[Sat Aug 15 2020 17:42:19.350]  LOG      props in image disp :  {"dataLen": 2, "ht": 352.8, "img_source": "file:///data/user/0/com.xyz_app2/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/2.jpg", "index": 0, "modalHt": 780.1354401805869, "modalWidth": 360, "sortFn": [Function move], "width": 352.8}  //<<== here is the value of props
[Sat Aug 15 2020 17:42:19.366]  LOG      object
[Sat Aug 15 2020 17:42:19.367]  LOG      ani code
[Sat Aug 15 2020 17:42:19.455]  LOG      props in image disp :  {"dataLen": 2, "ht": 352.8, "img_source": "file:///data/user/0/com.xyz_app2/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/7.jpg", "index": 1, "modalHt": 780.1354401805869, "modalWidth": 360, "sortFn": [Function move], "width": 352.8}
[Sat Aug 15 2020 17:42:19.467]  LOG      object
[Sat Aug 15 2020 17:42:19.484]  LOG      ani code
[Sat Aug 15 2020 17:42:20.868]  LOG      [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.img_source')]  //<<==here is the error
```

But there is an error saying that `this.props.img_source` is undefined when load an component:

```
                 <GridImage
                        img_source={img_source}  //<<==this line causes error as img_source undefined
                        width={width}
                        ht={ht}
                        indx={index}
                        modalWidth={modalWidth}
                        modalHt={modalHt}
                    />
```

It is a very straight forward object destructing. What is wrong here?

Comment: Where does your props come from? Does your data come from the request to the server?

Comment: The props is from call in parent component passed in as parameters. The console out has the value of props

Comment: This problem can be due to the fact that you receive data from the API, and because receiving information from the API is asynchronous, your child component is loaded before receiving the data. while console.log show data.